# getBytes from Firebase storageReference not working

Tags: android, firebase, bitmap, firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm creating my first app, in which I want to download pictures from Firebase storage into Bitmap, and then in turn change the phone's wallpaper.

Currently, the function does not get in neither

```
 onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
```

or to

```
 onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
```

Instead, it skips right to

```
return bmp[0];
```

I don't understand why, and what I'm doing wrong.

- Storage and storageRef are not null.

  ```
  public static Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {

      com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage storage = com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
      StorageReference gsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(url);

      if (bmp == null) {
          bmp = new Bitmap[1];
      }

       final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

       gsReference.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE)
      .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>(){            
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
              BitmapFactory.Options options = new 
              BitmapFactory.Options();
              options.inMutable = true;
              bmp[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, options);
          }
      }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
              int errorCode = ((StorageException) exception).getErrorCode();
              String errorMessage = exception.getMessage();
              Log.d("TAG", errorMessage + errorCode);
          }
      });
      return bmp[0];
  }
  ```

In my attempts, I tried to use Glide instead in the following way:

```
Glide.with(user.getmContext())
            .asBitmap()
            .load(url)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    bmp[0] = resource;
                }
            });
    return bmp[0];
```

But this did not produce any change, the onResourceReady (Bitmap resource) never gets called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for your result. Get bytes method is asynchronous that is why you're adding listeners and your value will be set after async task is done